# What is the equivalent of python's with open(file) in julia

Tags: julia, file-handling

Is there an equivalent to python's `with open()` idiom in Julia?

```py
>>> with open(path, "r") as file:
...    file.readlines()
['beep\n', 'boop\n']
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the most idiomatic way is, but you have several options:

```
julia> readlines("tmp.log")
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "beep"
 "boop"
```

```
julia> read(file, String)
"beep\nboop\n"
```

```
julia> open("tmp.log", "r") do file
           while !eof(file)
               @show readline(file)
           end
       end
readline(file) = "beep"
readline(file) = "boop"
```

```
julia> for line in eachline("tmp.log")
           @show line
       end
line = "beep"
line = "boop"
```

See the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.readline) for more.